# remove ips from regex pattern, js

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I have a pattern to validate url, it's working well, but i'd like to delete all validation from ip numbers:

```
const pattern= /^(?:(?:https?):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/
```

I've tried delete someting parts like this:

```
/^(?:(?:https?):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/
```

but i'm not sure if that is well

Comment: Sorry, but the pattern matches `regex101.com`. You say "*if user dont use www must to use http and https*". Do you want to match `regex101.com`? And do you want to match `http://333.333333.5555.7877656`? What kind of validation do you want to remove?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew on the original pattern there is 169, etc i think they are ip numbers i want just to remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply remove all the IP regex matching part (`(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))`) with an [**IP regex**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) pattern, `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}`:

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}|(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbFuaG/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string

  - `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - an optional string matching
  - `https?` - `http` or `https`
  - `:\/\/` - a `://` substring
  - `(?:` - start of a container group:
  - `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}` - IPv4 pattern
  - `|` - or

    - `(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*` - 0+ repetitions of a letter, digit or a char between `¡` (index 161) and `` (index 65535) followed with 0+ hyphens
    - `[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+` - 1+ letters, digits or chars between `¡` (index 161) and `` (index 65535)
    - `(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a dot followed with the two above subpatterns
    - `(?:\.[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})` - a dot followed with 2 or more repetitions of letters, digits or chars between `¡` (index 161) and `` (index 65535)
  - `)` - end of the container group
  - `(?::\d{2,5})?` - an optional substring starting with `:` and then 2 to 5 digits
  - `(?:\/\S*)?` - an optional substring starting with a `/` and then 0+ non-whitespace chars
  - `$` - end of string.